# Starting REST API server on Multiple independent nodes

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

My current setup includes following :

Fabric version : `1.1.0`

Composer version : `0.18.2`

**VM 1** - First machine running `fabric-samples/first-network/byfn.sh` - two organization setup - E2E successfully completed. Up and running with two REST API servers on different ports - `3000` and `3001`.

**VM 2** - 2nd machine was setup using same `fabric-samples/first-network` with custom `eyfn.sh` script - E2E successfully completed and joined network running on **VM 1**.

On **VM 2** - I run following commands before starting REST API servers

```
composer card create -p hospital1/byfn-network-hospital1.json -u chloe -n $network -c chloe/admin-pub.pem -k chloe/admin-priv.pem

composer card create -p hospital1/byfn-network-hospital1.json -u chloe -n lifelink-network -c chloe/admin-pub.pem -k chloe/admin-priv.pem

composer card import -f chloe@lifelink-network.card

composer network ping -c chloe@lifelink-network
```

> root@2c0f50fdb6f0:/var/www/app/current/credentials# composer network ping -c chloe@lifelink-network
>
> Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier 'ea173e6aa087cc9b0bfe433ed2f01c8ff939ac100a2b6d67b57cf3fe750cb83c', has not been registered
>
> Command failed

And `composer network ping` command is failing. I know for sure without success on this step, REST API server will not work.

I am not finding any documentation anywhere on how-to successfully do this.

Thank you

Comment: See https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org -  on VM2 the issue is your admin cert is not recognised by the CA server on that VM (it doesn't know that cert). You could try requesting an admin cert using `composer identity request` - see tutorial for assistance.

Comment: also noticed `root@2c0f50fdb6f0` in your output. One assumes you haven't installed the composer modules as root or sudo - but if you have, this can cause npm install issues / isn't supported as mentioned in this page (scroll down) https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html

Comment: Thanks Paul. I will try this out and post my findings here.